# How to add new row or column with text boxes when using ngFor with div to show table with different number of columns

Tags: angular

I have a grid system in which I made structure using following class :

```
export class MatrixDTO {
  constructor() {
    this.name = '';
    this.items = [];
  }
  name: string;
  items: Array<number>;
}
```

and on component its declared as an array of this class object :

```
 mat: MatrixDTO[] = [];
```

so far I am using static data to initialize this Array with following code on `ngOnInit()` method :

```
createBaseMatrix(): void {
    this.mat[this.mat.length] = new MatrixDTO();
    this.mat[0].name = 'ColumnA';
    this.mat[0].items.push(30);
    this.mat[0].items.push(35);
    this.mat[0].items.push(40);
    this.mat[this.mat.length] = new MatrixDTO();
    this.mat[1] = new MatrixDTO();
    this.mat[1].name = 'ColumnB';
    this.mat[1].items.push(34);
    this.mat[1].items.push(42);
    this.mat[1].items.push(69);
    this.mat[1].items.push(85);
    this.mat[1].items.push(96);
    this.mat[1].items.push(108);
  }
```

Now above same grid I have two link, one for add new row and other one for add new column , when user clicks on these buttons respective action should be performed on grid. I checked couple of existing grid libs available but those all are working only when you have fix length of columns but here in my case it can be different length for different rows.

I am new to angular so any idea will help or guide.
[example URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ntkfza?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Do you intend to pass row name on adding a row and row number and value on adding a column?

Comment: Did you mean row name like the ColumnA in above example , yes need text box for that in matrix it self  . and in case of columns values to text boxes in new column

Comment: I have updated my stackblitz with addRow and addCoumn functions , there is some css issue that you can ignore my only concern is instead of new row with labels I need text boxes , click on add column and see 99 is added I want that 99 in text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only make a table. You can "play" with the value "undefined".

We are going to create a function that return an array with the same elements that the max elements in the matrix array

```
  get rows() {
    return ".".repeat(this.mat.map(x => {
      return x.items.filter(i => i !== undefined).length
    }).reduce((a, b) => a > b ? a : b, 0)).split('')
  }
```

Now you can create a simple table

```
  <table>
      <thead>
          <th *ngFor="let col of mat">{{col.name}}</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let row of rows;let i=index">
              <td *ngFor="let col of mat;">
                  <input *ngIf="col.items[i]!==undefined" 
                       [(ngModel)]="col.items[i]">
                </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

In this simple I use [(ngModel)], you can use ReactiveForms if you want. The only know is, when you add a column, add with value "null", so replace the "thead" of the table with some like

```
  <th *ngFor="let col of mat">{{col.name}} 
      <button (click)="col.items.push(null)">Add</button>
  </th>
```

To add a Column simple

```
  <button (click)="Add()">Add Column</button>
  
  Add()
  {
    this.mat[this.mat.length] = new MatrixDTO()
  }
```

NOTE: Really use a getter to row is so ineffective, it's better create a function and, when we add a column in a row call the function

NOTE2: I make a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wpgr3n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), but I can not get work

**Update** when we has a table (or a divs) and we want to make it "editable" we need has two divs and a *ngIf, an example can be, e.g.

```
  <span *ngIf="cols!=99" style="padding: 5px; margin:5px">
      {{cols}}</span>

  <input #input *ngIf="cols==99" style="padding: 5px; margin:5px" 
         (blur)="cols=input.value" [value]="cols">
```

Well, really I don't like use a value like "99", we can use `===null` and `!==null` and give value "null"

Another way is to has two variables to allow us to edit any value. Imagine we has two variables

```
rowSelected:number=-1;
colSelected:number=-1;
```

we need add to our *ngFor let i=index and let j=index -to know in with column/index we are so out loops can be like

```
<div *ngFor="let row of mat;let i=index">
  {{row.name}}
  <div *ngFor="let cols of row.items;let j=index" >
    <span (click)="rowSelected=i;colSelected=j" 
        *ngIf="cols!==null || i!=rowSelected || j!=colSelected" 
         style="padding: 5px; margin:5px">
        {{cols}}
    </span>
    <input #input *ngIf="cols===null || (i==rowSelected && j==colSelected)" 
       style="padding: 5px; margin:5px"
       (blur)="cols=input.value;rowSelected=-1;colSelected=-1"
       [value]="cols">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated my stackblitz with addRow and addCoumn functions , there is some css issue that you can ignore my only concern is instead of new row with labels I need text boxes , click on add column and see 99 is added I want that 99 in text box

Comment: and also added one more prop as custom to get to know which row is added by add new row click event but problem is how to identify columns ?

Comment: you can get it creating  for each element a span and a input and use two simple `*ngIf: ` to show one or another. I updated the answer, I hope give you a clue

Comment: Now only issue I am facing CSS , so trying to resolve that as well.